# Java thread changing data and thread serving data to users using websocket

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, abstraction

I'm planning on developing a java application, which works as a WebSocket server. Basic idea is to reduce sql queries number, by having an ArrayList storing all the data needed, and updating them once per minute. My idea is to create one class having data stored inside, and another which is extending class Thread, and updating data in the data-storing class. My question is whether it is a good approach, and what are other options. I'm affraid, about situation, when WebSocket thread is "paused", and user sends request in that very moment. What will happen in theory?

Comment: Hum are you just doing this to learn or for a true projcet ? For a true project, i recommend you first to learn to use an ORM like Hibernate or EclipseLink, **well used** (ofc badly it ca be worst...) they reduce significatively the number of queries throw to the server. Aniway, SO is about debugging an existing code, you question is either too broad or primarly opinion based and is so off topic. Finally, if you want to use something that is like websocket, why not using real websocket and a java websocketclient ? Unless it's in order to learn, there is no need to redo the wheel.

Comment: To answer it should be necessary to know the amount of data you think your app could store inside this ArrayList, and the expected throughput too.

Comment: There are going to be arrayLists in arrayLists, storing up to 100 objects, with about 10 fields, input type is going to be JSON, giving me user id and token, and data request

Comment: If you are going to do this by yourself you have to consider that is not as easy at could appear. Considering List are not so fast to access, if you search often, and you have to think about the thread safe code you need. How many client will interact, and how many queries are you expecting from each?

Comment: Between 100-200 clients from browser, each 1 query per 10 seconds

Comment: The worst case you have 200 queries per second, so you have to 10 seconds to answer before you receive the next 200 queries, this means you have 50 milliseconds per query.  If you want to avoids an ORM, consider some in memory db or cache db noSQL like key value, instead to do it yourself with Lists of Lists.

Comment: @Berrigan Add your clarifications and additional info by editing the Question rather than as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a database

If your Question is practical rather than academic (intellectual curiosity), then the answer is simple: Use a database.

One of the main proposes to a database is to efficiently and safely handle multiple threads changing data and simultaneous queries. Why re-invent the wheel, especially a *very* tricky wheel?

Something like the [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) seems like a good fit to your needs. This kind of product can even run embedded within your app.

If you do not care about persisting data to storage, you can make it run as an [“in memory” database](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) for even more speed.